# Multiple measures model statistical tests

Tags: statistics, static-analysis, statistical-test

What test to conduct when I wanna see if different measures vary in the same way for all subjects. I’m working on glucose data and have repetitive measures for blood glucose levels throughout the day. I want to see if the levels of fasting glucose and post meal glucose vary in the same way for all of my subjects (within subjects variation is the same between subjects)

Comment: I have voted to migrate this question to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), because it seems to be more a question about statistics than about R code. Also, here is a [Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/490029/can-a-levene-test-be-insignificant-even-if-the-variances-of-the-two-groups-look) that might be useful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.